# Which lines in $\mathbb R^2$ define a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

> Which lines in $\mathbb R^2$ define a subgroup?

I know that the line $y=x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ gives a subgroup, but I can't figure out the other ones.

Comment: HINT: Every vector subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Hint: a subgroup must contain the identity.

Comment: [see this](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqsdS01aXJAhWiF6YKHQi6A-gQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.wisc.edu%2F~chandara%2FsubspacesofR2.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGwQeVB43uE0uephkcrC2OZuq2Cfg)

Comment: So all the straight lines that pass through the origin are subgroups?

Comment: Correct. The line must pass through the origin, as $(0,0)$ is the identity of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now just verify that any such line is a subgroup.